# Spring Boot with multiple DispatcherServlet, each having their own @Controllers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-boot, spring-4

Basically I want to split my application into 2 parts. Each part has it's own security stuff and own `@Controller`s. The `@Services` should be accessible from both parts.

So I thought, I should get 2 `DispatcherServlet`. One listening to `/admin/*` and the second listening to everything else ( `/` ). Each of those will have its own `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` so I can have separate component scan for the `@Controller`s.

And because Spring Boot provides one `DispatcherServlet` listening on `/` out of the box, I thought, I can just add a second one:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean(name="myDS")
    public DispatcherServlet myDS(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        webContext.setParent(applicationContext);
        webContext.register(MyConfig2.class);
        // webContext.refresh();
        return new DispatcherServlet(webContext);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean mySRB(@Qualifier("myDS") DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet) {
        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet);
        servletRegistrationBean.addUrlMappings("/admin/*");
        servletRegistrationBean.setName("adminServlet");
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }
}
```

The `MyConfig2` class, only has `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan`. Within the same package is a `@Controller`.

When starting the application, I can see, that the second servlet mapping is getting registered, but the `@Controller` is not. Additionally I can now access **all** `@Controllers` from `/` **and** `/admin`.

---

Any idea how I can get this working?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I got it working somehow!

Here's my Package Layout:

```
test.foo.
         FooConfig.java
         FooController.java
test.bar.
         BarConfig.java
         BarController.java
test.app.
         Application.java
         MyService.java
src/main/resources/application.properties
```

**Application.java:**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude=DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean foo() {
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();   
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.register(FooConfig.class);
        dispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet, "/foo/*");
        servletRegistrationBean.setName("foo");
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean bar() {
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.register(BarConfig.class);
        dispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet, "/bar/*");
        servletRegistrationBean.setName("bar");
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }
}
```

- The `exclude` does prevent Spring Boot from creating its own `DispatcherServlet` with `/` mapping. You can remove that line, if you want that mapping or define your own.
- You can add `servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1)` if you want to have your Servlets initialized on application start. Else it will wait for the first request for that servlet.
- It's important to set `servletRegistrationBean.setName(...)`, else the servlets will override each other.

**FooConfig.java & BarConfig.java:**

```
@Configuration @ComponentScan @EnableWebMvc
public class FooConfig { }
```

- `@EnableWebMvc` will enable the component scan. Without it, it won't find the `@Controller` class.

**The Controller and Service code** is not important. You just have to know, that if you have `@RequestMapping("/foo")` inside `FooController`, the request must be `GET /foo/foo` because the Servlet's URL mapping is `/foo/*`. It's not possible to call the URL `GET /foo` because the Servlet URL mapping needs a `/` at the end of its path (in other words: `GET /foo` will look for a Servlet with `/` mapping!), though `@RequestMapping("")` must be called via `GET /foo/`. And of course it was not possible to use `/foo` or `/foo*` as Servlet mapping (or I just did not find the correct settings for that)

**Scope:** The Controllers can't *see* each other, though it's **not** possible to `@Autowired` them in each other. Also the Service can't `@Autowired` any of the Controllers. **But** the Controllers can `@Autowired` the Service.

Though it's a classical parent child context hierarchy.

The only "bad" thing is, that we need `@EnableMvcConfig` and don't get the auto configured sugar from Spring boot within the context. The parent context is getting auto configured. I put some database stuff within the `application.properties` and did a query inside `MyService` which got called by `FooController` and it worked flawlessly! `:)`

I hope this may help some people!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Really helps. I have one more challenge to overcome. How can I authenticate+authorize(DB based) the /foo endpoints but only authenticate the /bar endpoints? I have a configuration from here[0]. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909226/how-to-configure-waffle-in-spring-using-java-configuration

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, I was struggling with same problem and found that @EnableMvcConfig is required after reading your answer.

Comment: Thanks for that thorough explanation! It helped me to solve two different problems. I mean it's common to self-answer with "this works:" plus the code bits without explanation...

Comment: why we need FooConfig.java because it is empty class.

Comment: @DHARMENDRASINGH FooConfig.java has annotations that will cause Spring to scan for components, enable Spring Web MVC, etc.

Comment: I received the following error: `Parameter 1 of constructor in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletPath' that could not be found.`
I had to add also this configuration: `@Bean public DispatcherServletPath dispatcherServletPath1() { return () -> "/"; }`

Comment: @Benjamin Aren't you supposed to specify the exact `Foo` or `Bar` `@Controller`'s packages in their respective `ConfigFoo` and `ConfigBar` `@ComponentScan` parts? By the way, there is no `@EnableMvcConfig` but rather `@EnableWebMvc`.

Comment: setting the name was crucial for me!